# Why is my windows service executable not found?

Tags: windows, service

I am creating a service using the following command in cmd.exe run with administrator privileges:

```
 C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc.exe create Cloudflared binPath= 
 'C:\LocalServices\cloudflared.exe' displayname= "CloudFlared"
 [SC] CreateService SUCCESS
```

I check that it's there:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc.exe queryex Cloudflared

SERVICE_NAME: Cloudflared
    TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
    STATE              : 1  STOPPED
    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 1077  (0x435)
    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
    CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
    WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
    PID                : 0
    FLAGS              :
```

Then I try to start it:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc.exe start Cloudflared
[SC] StartService FAILED 2:

The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Check what is listed under a dir of C:\LocalServices (since that is my binPath directory)

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dir C:\LocalServices
Volume in drive C is OS
Volume Serial Number is 86C2-13A2

Directory of C:\LocalServices

13/07/2022  17:28    <DIR>          .
13/07/2022  17:28    <DIR>          ..
12/07/2022  21:01        32,173,056 cloudflared.exe
           1 File(s)     32,173,056 bytes
           2 Dir(s)  263,158,734,848 bytes free
```

Sure enough, cloudflared.exe is definitely there, so why does `sc start` say it can't find it?

Comment: You can't just run random programs as a service.

Comment: It isn't a random program. It is a program designed by be run as a service and is part of Cloudflare's Zero Trust. See https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-apps/install-and-setup/installation/#running-multiple-instances-in-windows

Comment: Then I don't know. Perhaps the people on Superuser.com can help you...

Comment: You could try runing Process Monitor when starting the service to see what files its looking for & in what locations.